# Is there any way to execute Windows cmd commands from the IDLE editor?

Tags: python, cmd, pip

I want to run all command line statements from the IDLE editor of Python. Are there any supporting libraries with functions to execute the desired task?

For instance, in Windows cmd, we can write:

```
C:\Users\Desktop\Lucky>py -m pip install pandas
```

Instead of doing it via cmd, can we execute the same command from the IDLE editor?

Comment: This is probably a question for your systems administrator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your safest and legal way of installing pandas is to ask your system administrator to do so. You could get in trouble for circumventing any rules set by your system administrator.